# Make external drive connected to TimeCapsule appears as one drive with internal hard drive

Tags: external-hard-drive, time-capsule

I have a TimeCapsule with an external drive connected. Right now I see in Finder two separate units.

I would like to make both hard drives (internal and external) appears as if they were a single disk.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can add external hard drives for network access but Time Machine will only backup to one single drive and will not combo drives for storage space.